# HTML5 audio wav 13kbps

Tags: php, jquery, html5, linux

me mandan audios en formato **.wav** con un bitrate de **13kbps** que necesito reproducir en una etiqueta audio. El problema es que los navegadores, por lo que he investigado, soportan wav de 8 o 16 kbps.

He probado reproductores jQuery como jPlayer y nada...
Por lo que ahora estoy probando desde consola en linux a convertir ese audio a un wav con bitrate 8-16 o mp3 para hacer el exec() en el php de carga de audios a mi web.

Estoy usando sox y lame, pero no doy con el comando correcto. He usado la última respuesta del post: https://superuser.com/questions/62048/converting-wav-ccitt-a-law-format-to-mp3-using-lame pero genera entre medias un archivo cdr bastante pesado y hace el proceso muy lento.

¿Alguna alternativa o comando concreto para convertir el bitrate del wav o convertir a mp3 sin generar ese cdr (si intento convertir el wav directamente me da error de codificación)?

soxi del audio:

```
Input File     : 'out.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 8000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:03:58.32 = 1906560 samples ~ 17874 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 387k
Bit Rate       : 13.0k
Sample Encoding: GSM
```

Comment: Puede que [esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905583/convert-wav-to-mp3-using-lame-from-php) tenga la solución a tu problema.

Comment: No, me devuelve _Unsupported data format: 0x0031_ al intentar convertir wav con ese bitrate a mp3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Me devuelve: "Unsupported data format: 0x0031"

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Usando [`sox`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sox), convertir el `wav` encodeado en `GSM` a `PCM`:

  ```
  sox in.wav -r 8k -c 1 -s out.wav
  ```
- Luego usando [`lame`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lame), convertir el `wav PCM` a `MP3`:

  ```
  lame out.wav out.mp3
  ```

// Update

Debido al [comentario que el archivo resultante es demasiado grande](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46301/html5-audio-wav-13kbps/46330?noredirect=1#comment81779_46330), también podrías hacerlo así:

Usando [`ffmpeg`](https://ffmpeg.org/)

```
ffmpeg -i prueba.wav -vn -ab 8k -ac 2 -f mp3 prueba.mp3
```

Donde:

```
-vn                 disable video
-ab bitrate         audio bitrate
-ac channels        set number of audio channels
-f fmt              force format
```

Comment: usando `sox in.wav -r 8k -c 1 -e signed-integer out.wav` (-s is deprecated) te crea un archivo .wav de 6Mb cuando el original es de 0.5Mb, puede ser una solución a corto plazo ya que ralentiza bastante la carga

Comment: @PriNcee, ¿podrías dejar el enlace de descarga a un archivo de ejemplo?

Comment: https://mega.nz/#!KNE0CZJY!cDWZStdsPIUIH59TKH9CNuRyhMGx-KZH_X6Zn6HZAzY